# CPU platform is changing after resizing the instance

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am using GCE for nested virtualization. I am aware of the specific CPU architecture to be used for nested-virtualization compatibility.

Everything is going smoothly and I am using this feature without any issues, however, if I apply the recommendation for instance resizing I noticed that this feature 'nesting virt.' is not available.

I know this by running command `grep -cw vmx /proc/cpuinfo` and `lsmod`.

Comment: Please can you explain what you mean by " if I apply the recommendation for instance resizing". Are you following a guide? If so, please provide a link. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [a known bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/74331427) in Google Compute Engine. Instances can run nested VMs on first boot, but on subsequent boots cannot run nested VMs. You may follow the issue to be notified of updates.